# rbind is overwriting previous data in R

Tags: r

So, I have had two questions here and I combined the solutions, but it seems I am not implementing them well. ([Q1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61127524/more-effective-way-to-filter-data-in-r/61127681#61127681) [Q2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61049085/appending-file-name-to-data-frame-in-r))

So, I am reading files using **read_delim()** and trying to filter out some data before saving them into one data type.

```
data <- data.frame()
for (file in files){

  name = strsplit(file, split = "\\.")[[1]][1]

  tmp <- data %>% bind_rows(read_delim(file = file, delim = ";", col_types = cols(
    a = col_double(),
    b = col_double(),
    c = col_character()
    )) %>% mutate(filename = name)
    data_tmp <- tmp %>%
      filter(!str_detect(c, 'a'))
    data <- rbind(data, tmp_data)
}
```

Apparently, the problem I had in the first question has reappeared. Looks like that **mutate(filename = name)** always gets the value from the last element that was read.

Comment: @akrun yes, sorry about it, I was just trying to write another example, without giving my real code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We could make it more compact if we use `map`.  Loop over the `files`, read the data with `read_delim`, create the 'filename' column with substring of the filename, `filter` the rows and convert it to a single data.frame with `_dfr` suffix

```
library(purrr)
library(dplyr)
out <- map_dfr(files, ~ {
          file <- .x
         read_delim(file, delim = ";", col_types = cols(
            a = col_double(),
            b = col_double(),
            c = col_character()
            )) %>%
          mutate(filename = str_remove(file, "\\..*")) %>%
          filter(!str_detect(c, 'a'))
        })
```

---

In the OP's `for` loop, the `data %>% bind_rows` is not needed because we are already `rbind`ing the 'tmp_data` in each iteration

```
data <- data.frame()
for (file in files){

  name = strsplit(file, split = "\\.")[[1]][1]

  tmp <- read_delim(file = file, delim = ";", col_types = cols(
    a = col_double(),
    b = col_double(),
    c = col_character()
    )) %>% mutate(filename = name)
    tmp_data <- tmp %>%
      filter(!str_detect(c, 'a'))
    data <- rbind(data, tmp_data)
}
```

Comment: Can't thank you enough.. I still need to learn some things, I keep missing some small details in code, that is causing all the trouble